# How to match all question marks except for the last one

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match all question marks except for the last one in a sentence. For example:

> Here is the first sentence??

Expected output: Here is the first sentence?

> Here is the second sentence?

Expected output: Here is the second sentence

> Here is the third sentence???

Expected output: Here is the third sentence??

I have tried the following code, but it does not work.

```py
re.match(r'(.*?)\?', sentence).group()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

- greedy repetition
- repetition of the question mark
- [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) with [`group(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group)

See:

```
In [31]: re.search(r'([^?]*\?*)\?', 'aa???? ').group(1)
Out[31]: 'aa???'

In [32]: re.search(r'([^?]*\?*)\?', 'Here is a sentence ????? ').group(1)
Out[32]: 'Here is a sentence ????'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X2fDyU/1)

Comment: This is the best approach. Just make `.*` lazy, and remove the space: `r'(.*?\?*)\?'`. See https://regex101.com/r/P3xNfe/1/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Better use a lookahead than capturing groups

Comment: @inetphantom That is a moot statement. In this case, a lookahead does not seem to be necessary: no overlapping matches, no specific restriction of a generic pattern is necessary.

Comment: Ah and the selection of questionmarks in between is pointless as `.*` also selects them

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't like lazy operator, I just limited options of the greedy one with `[^?]*`, it has more stable performance.

Answer (score 0):

Regex approach:

```
import re

s = 'Here is the third sentence???'
res = re.search(r'[^?]+\?*(?=\?)', s).group(0)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
Here is the third sentence??
```

---

- `[^?]+` - match any char(s) expect `?`
- `\?*` - match zero or more question mark char(s). `?` char should be escaped as a special character.
- `(?=\?)` - positive lookahead assertion: ensures that a before-matched sentence part is followed by a single `?` (question mark)

Comment: @inetphantom, where did you see the action "to add them again" ?

Comment: you first select everything that's not a questionmark and then add the questionmarks at the end to the selection. This is a) pointless and b) introduces to not work for sentences with ?questionmarks in betweeen.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)\?
```

The problem is the lazy quantifier '?' which tries to match as few as possible, when you want to match as many as possible.
Also:

```
.group()
```

will return zero group bu default which means the whole match. What you need is the first group:

```
re.match(r'(.*)\?', sentence).group(1)
```

Consider using simple if statement if you just want to remove last question mark:

```
if sentence[-1] == '?':
    sentence = sentence[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = re.search(r'(\w\?)', str1)
str1[0:results.span()[0]+1] + str1[results.span()[1]:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use re.sub to delete question mark not followed by question mark:

```
re.sub(r'\?(?!\?)','',text)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following regex will work.

.+(?=\?)

[image]